# Need help handling nested iframes

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, nested, recaptcha

I am trying to handle the yahoo sign up capcha. I am using Selenium and Python.

My code is like this.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "recaptcha-iframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//iframe[contains(@title,"reCAPTCHA")]')))
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="recaptcha-anchor"]')))
```

Switching the frames does work I think. At least there is no "no such frame" error.

I can locate everything in the first iframe without any problem.
However I cannot locate any element in the last iframe.

Spent hours on it and still cannot figure it out. This approach works on other nested iframe examples but yahoo page is killing me.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Edit 1:

Here is the relevant HTML part

```
<span class="recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" id="recaptcha-anchor" tabindex="0" dir="ltr" aria-labelledby="recaptcha-anchor-label"><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-border" role="presentation"></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-borderAnimation" role="presentation"></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinner" role="presentation"><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinner-overlay"></div></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark" role="presentation"></div></span>
```

Btw this problem does not occur if I use Firefox. Do browsers behave differently or is this just a bug?

Edit 2:

Here is the page URL

```
https://login.yahoo.com/account/challenge/recaptcha?intl=us&specId=yidreg&context=reg&done=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com%2F&authMechanism=reg&authCredentialsType=WyJjb29raWVzIl0%3D&sessionIndex=QQ--&acrumb=cuevf59A
```

Comment: Relevant HTML of the element in the last iframe?

Comment: If it is a `yahoo sign up capcha` could you share page URL ? I believe it will be a public url

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the function to execute javascript inside nested iframe.

```
    def execute_js_element_inside_iframe(self, by, value, script):
        """
        Gets the element inside the first iframe with the given locator, including nested iframes.
        Sample Usage: By.ID, submit, arguments[0].click()
        Note: script must start with arguments[0] and then as needed.
        """
        element = self.find_element(by, value)
        if element is not None:
            return self.driver.execute_script(script, element)

        frames = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//iframe')

        for frame in frames:
            try:
                self.driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
            except:
                pass
            else:
                element = self.find_element(by, value)
                if element is not None:
                    return self.driver.execute_script(script, element)

                # Recursive call to handle nested iframes
                mvalue = self.execute_js_element_inside_iframe(by, value, script)
                if mvalue is not None:
                    return mvalue
            finally:
                self.driver.switch_to.parent_frame()

        # If no element is found in any iframe, return None
        return None
```